# Measure prosodic similarity using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, signal-processing

I have a dataset of 12,000 audio recordings of nonnative learners imitating the prosody of native speakers (300 samples for each native speaker utterance). All the nonnative learners' attempts were rated by experts on a scale of 1-4 in terms of how similar the learners' speech prosody was to the native speakers targets. Cross correlation and Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) were traditionally used to model prosodic similarity. But I wonder:

1. if deep learning algorithms will predict prosodic similarity with much higher accuracy than these older methods and therefore I should use deep-learning;
2. which deep learning algorithm(s) is/are right for this task because there are deep neural networks, deep belief networks, deep reinforcement learning, recurrent neural networks and convolutional neural networks;
3. if the size of the dataset is large enough for training robust deep learning models.

I am familiar with the concepts of supervised machine learning (e.g. glmnet, random forest, gbm) and speech prosody, but I am totally new to deep learning. I am learning Keras now. Any help with my questions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conventional wisdom is that increasing training size with diverse data will produce highly performing models with deep learning. You may want to check out  [Torch Audio](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/index.html).